# Bytecode Hotswap - perplex

Tags: java, bytecode-hot-swap

I have no idea anymore. Since today 14pm the hot-code replace does not work anymore. 
I had jdk8_74x64 installed on win10x64.

I test it using this code in a simple project (without maven and without dependencies):

```
public class Test{
  public static void main(String[] args){
    System.out.println("hi"); // breakpoint here, it stops always

    System.out.println("ho"); // on suspending i change this to "hoy".
  }
}
```

1. Start eclipse with new workspace - still not working
2. Restart computer - still not working
3. Uninstall all JDK/JRE and remove all `javaws.exe`, install again - still not working.
4. Uninstall eclipse, reinstall eclipse - still not working
5. Installed netbeans, using "apply code changes" - still not working.
6. Delete jdk with all `javaws.exe`, delete eclipse, uninstall netbeans, use new user, install jdk 8u31x64 install netbeans - still not working
7. Installed idea-community-edition15+jetbrains, change `ho` to `hoy` and apply class-changes (idea notifies me `1 class reloaded`) - still not working.

How to get hot-code-replace working?

Comment: From your question it is not even clear what you want to _achieve_....

Comment: @fge see my edit, is it clear now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hm,

```
public class Test{
  public static void main(String[] args){
    System.out.println("hi"); // breakpoint here, it stops always

    System.out.println("ho"); // on suspending i change this to "hoy".
  }
}
```

does not work but

```
public class Test{
  public static void main(String[] args){
    foobar();
  }
  public static void foobar(){
    System.out.println("hi"); // breakpoint here, it stops always

    System.out.println("ho"); // on suspending i change this to "hoy".
  }
}
```

Works great everywhere.

Comment: So what you really want is byte code hot swapping at runtime. If you are on IRC, I suggest that you ask Maldivia on ##freenode's Java. He is a JVM guru and a driving force behind JRebel (mostly due to his technical skills in the matter)

Comment: @fge I changed the tag from hot-code-replace to bytecode-hot-swap.